# Issue during Upgrade of Azure functions to .NET 8 and isolated workers

Tags: azure-functions, .net-8.0, dotnet-isolated

Hi I upgrading my workers to dotnet 8 and isolated worker.
I have removed the `Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs.Extensions.ServiceBus` dependency as suggested in document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-dotnet-to-isolated-model?tabs=net8#programcs-file.

But now I am getting error in Program.cs file for line:

```
services.Configure<ServiceBusOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AutoCompleteMessages = false;
});
```

with ServiceBusOptions  that it cannot be found.
What can I do here?

here is my hostbuilder function,

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services => {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.Configure<ServiceBusOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AutoCompleteMessages = false;
        });
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

I am not sure what to do, since I am new to .NET and Azure, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think quite a lot changed with Service Bus usage from Isolated functions. Lots of the Bindings are very different, too. Maybe start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?tabs=isolated-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?tabs=isolated-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp) @*Andrew B*.

I got the same error when I tried to implement the same in my environment.

> The type or namespace name 'ServiceBusOptions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Refer the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=python-v2,isolated-process,nodejs-v4,extensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#example) for the example code.

To set `AutoCompleteMessages= false`, add the attribute in the function code as shown below:

```cs
[Function(nameof(Function1))]
public async Task Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "demo", AutoCompleteMessages = false)]
    ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
    ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Message ID: {id}", message.MessageId);
    _logger.LogInformation("Message Body: {body}", message.Body);
    _logger.LogInformation("Message Content-Type: {contentType}", message.ContentType);

    // Complete the message
    await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
}
```

**Program.cs:**

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**Sending message:**

[image]

**Console Response:**

[image]